# Redirecting a specific https request to http

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I know there are other pages out there that cover https to http but they all seem to mainly cover doing it for the whole site.

Basically what I'm trying to do is.... we have one section of our site that is served over `https` but in the header it includes a search field, this is currently pointed to `http`, but this is causing a *warning icon* in Chrome so we need to change it to `https`.

The search page it directs to is not setup to be served over `https` so we just want to redirect any `https` requests to that page to the `http` equivalent.

So for example:

```
https://www.example.com/search.php
```

gets redirected to:

```
http://www.example.com/search.php
```

...and:

```
https://www.example.com/search.php?term=foo&cat=bar
```

get redirected to:

```
http://www.example.com/search.php?term=foo&cat=bar
```

I was reading [this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html) but still am not quite sure how to do it properly.

Also, not 100% sure where in my current `.htaccess` file to put it, this is our current file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*),(.*)$ $2.php?rewrite_params=$1&page_url=$2

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*(.*) [OR] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C).*script.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|[|%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|[|%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]

RewriteRule ^stores/([0-9a-z.-]+)/?$ shop.php?shop_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^stores/([0-9a-z.-]+)/ajax_files/watch_item\.php$ ajax_files/watch_item.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^stores/([0-9a-z.-]+)/ajax_files/save_field\.php$ ajax_files/save_field.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^stores/([0-9a-z.-]+)/images/form-cb-icons\.png$ images/form-cb-icons.png [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^group-break/([0-9]+)/[0-9a-z.-]+/?$ group_break.php?cb_id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^group-breaks/([a-z]+)-[a-z-]+/?$ group_breaks.php?tab=$1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^afltcc$ /register.php?partner_id=100 [L,NC]
```

Can it be put anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule to redirect request for (HTTPS) search.php to it's (HTTP) search.php along with all the query parameters in the request.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^search.php$    http://%{HTTP_HOST}/search.php [R=301,L]
```

I would recommend placing this above all the non-redirectional rewrite rules on your `.htaccess`

Comment: How does that do all the query parameters as well? I thought you needed to add in the `QSA` in there?

Comment: Query string is carried over **as is** to target URL if target has no `?` in it. `QSA` is not needed here.

Comment: @Brett Not required. It is required only if you are adding new query parameters in the redirection. [Read this for more explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26410477/2745300)

Comment: Oh ok thanks guys. Also, last question - can you clarify a bit more where to place this? Not 100% sure where you meant.

Comment: Place it just below `RewriteEngine On` line.