# Htacces redirect subfolder to another subfolder without change url

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework

I have a zend framework application running inside the folder test

```
domain.com/test
```

However for me to access I need to use

`domain.com/test/public`

I want to know how to do in htacess to be able to access using only

```
domain.com/test
```

Comment: I believe you'd want to use `[L,QSA]` as the flags to your rewriterule.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess - silently rewrite/redirect everything to internal subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26405204/htaccess-silently-rewrite-redirect-everything-to-internal-subfolder)

Comment: I have not been able to make it work yet